# How to use tiny-aes 128 library in c?

Tags: c, encryption, aes

I would like to encrypt using tiny AES library (https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-c) in C for AES128.

My code is as below:

```
    unsigned char cipher[64];
    unsigned char in[] = "THJmaoeuf2jsn4jebc7ak3mUdnyHeklOYopdna/OOndu3bis/E7jTd/enasduR3h";   //64 bits

    printf("Size of AES input msg: %d \n", sizeof(in));              

    unsigned char key[] = "Gns7AauH3dnaod==";    //16 bits
    unsigned char IV[] = "vhdNaleuTHenaOlL";     //16 bits

    printf("cipher(before): %x \n", cipher);

    AES128_CBC_encrypt_buffer(cipher, in, 64, key, IV);

    for(int n=0; n<64; n++){
        printf("cipher[%d]: %x \n", n, cipher);
    }
```

The function I am using from tiny AES 128 library is this :

```
void AES128_CBC_encrypt_buffer(uint8_t* output, uint8_t* input, uint32_t length, const uint8_t* key, const uint8_t* iv)
```

However, the last line of printing 'cipher' is empty. I believe it should print the cipher text of the original input after encryption. Is this the correct way to use the library? Thank you.

**EDIT:** I updated the code here, in which 'cipher' is now printing characters but in a strange way. It prints the same thing before and after encryption, which should not be the case. This is the same case even when I changed the 'key' and 'IV' to be 16 bits and input message 'in' as 64 bits. Here is a part of the output:

```
cipher(before): 20003A34
cipher[0]: 20003A34
cipher[1]: 20003A34
cipher[2]: 20003A34
         .
         .
cipher[63]: 20003A34
```

Comment: You need to allocate memory to hold the cipher. Currently, your `cipher` does not point to writeable memory. Have a look in the example code in the `test.c`-file in the repository for guidelines: https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-c/blob/master/test.c . Disclaimer: I'm the main author of the project

Comment: How do you know the first char in the cipher isn't `'\0'`?  Best to loop over `cipher` and output the hex values of each char. (and check the guidelines cited above -- I don't know who provides storage there)

Comment: You can only use the `%s` format specifier for C-style strings. You can't use it to print arbitrary data with no special structure. For one thing, how would it know how many bytes to print?

Comment: Your IV and Key should be 16 bytes / 128 bits long (currently 24 + null-termination = 25). You should also pad your buffers so that their sizes are multiples of 16 bytes (128 bit) as mentioned in the project README :) Currently you're passing a 64 byte array (+ 1 byte 0-termination) and telling `AES_CBC_encrypt_buffer` the length is 65 (because you're using `sizeof(in)` to determine that).

Comment: @MortenJensen I tried changing IV and Key to random string of 16 bytes each, and the 'in' input as random string of 32 bytes, and also replaces 'sizeof(in)' to be 32 now. I am able to print out using %x, but it prints '20003A74' for each byte of the encrypted string (cipher). Even before encryption, I tried printing 'cipher' (which should be empty since it is declared as 'unsigned char ciphertext[32]') but it prints '20003A74' as well. What has gone wrong here? Sorry, I'm new to this. Thank you.

Comment: @jj_94 Did you try reading the file I suggested? The `test.c` file from the repository encrypts and decrypts strings and prints them out as well. You could have a look in that file for some inspiration on how to get what you want. Update the question to contain your code, if you need help with that :)

Comment: @MortenJensen I had a look in the file you suggested. It seem that I am doing the same way, except my 'in' needs to be a string and i do not have 'out' variable. On a side note, I updated the question to my recent code. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Your code has undefined behavior.

This:

```
unsigned char *cipher = "";
```

makes `cipher` into a pointer to a single byte with the value 0 (the string terminator). It's a bit fishy since string literals are not guaranteed to be `unsigned char` (they're just `char` which is either signed or unsigned) but I think it will build.

This doesn't give you any writeable space, since string literals are read-only, so trying to write an entire encrypted block in there will give you undefined behavior.

To fix it you need:

```
unsigned char in[] = "THJmaoeuf2jsn4jebc7ak3mUdnyHeklOYopdna/OOndu3bis/E7jTd/enasduR3h";   //64 bits
unsigned char cipher[sizeof in];
```

Also, the encrypted data is very likely not a valid C string, it can contain 0-bytes and thus won't print correctly using `printf("%s", ...);` anyway.

Comment: I agree with @DavidC.Rankin - I would say cipher points to 1 byte of read-only const data.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Of course you're right, that'll teach me not to answer questions pre-coffee. Edited of course. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, that fixed the problem of not displaying any character out. However it is showing strange characters now. Why is that so?

Comment: @jj_94 Try printing each byte in the string with the hex-format string `%x`. An encrypted string will contain unprintable characters, which is probably what you are seeing as "strange characters". It seems you are expecting that ASCII input gives ASCII output - this is not the case.

Comment: @jj_94 That is addressed in my answer's final paragraph. Encrypted data is not text, it's binary (regardless of the input).

Answer (score 2):

in the line:

```
printf("cipher[%d]: %x \n", n, cipher);
```

change that to be:

```
printf("cipher[%d]: %x \n", n, cipher[n]);
```

That way, each byte of the cipher is outputted instead of the address of cipher which is what you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

in aes.h  select 128 by

```
#define AES128 1
```

and below is a sample for Encryption & Decryption

```
struct AES_ctx ctx;

uint8_t key[] = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
uint8_t iv[]  = "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb";
uint8_t str[] = "This a sample text, Length eq 32";

printf("\n raw buffer \n");
for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
    printf("%.2x", str[i]);
}

AES_init_ctx_iv(&ctx, key, iv);
AES_CBC_encrypt_buffer(&ctx, str, 32);

printf("\n Encrypted buffer\n");

for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
    printf("%.2x", str[i]);
}

printf("\n Decrypted buffer\n");

AES_init_ctx_iv(&ctx, key, iv);
AES_CBC_decrypt_buffer(&ctx, str, 32);

for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
    printf("%.2x", str[i]);
}

printf("\n");
```

*Note:  there is no padding is provided so for CBC and ECB, All buffers should be multiples of 16 bytes.